# is @ComponentScan really optional?

Tags: java, spring

I saw in a tutorial that says that using @ComponentScan in the java configuration file is optional but when I ran my code without @ComponentScan It gave me an error.

The code itself does not matter. I just added it for a better understanding

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context=new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SportConfig.class);

    Coach baseBallCoach= context.getBean("baseBallCoach", Coach.class);
    System.out.println(baseBallCoach.getDailyWorkout());
    System.out.println(baseBallCoach.getDailyFortune());
    context.close();
```

output:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'baseBallCoach' available
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:863)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1160)
at org.isoft.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is optional, but without it you will have by far more work with configuring all your beans. With `@ComponentScan` any class annotated with `@Component` `@Service` and few other annotations will be automatically discovered. If you don't use `@ComponentScan` you have to define all your beans in `@Configuration` class with `@Bean` or in some other way. So, while `@ComponentScan` is optional you would want to use it in most cases.

Comment: Thanks can you give me a link to know how to make beans without using @ComponentScan.

Comment: Look up how to use '@Bean' annotation in '@Configuration' file. You can start from here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean